# Retrieve Internet explorer proxy settings from the registry

Tags: go, windows, configuration

I just re-wrote a library to easily retrieve the proxy settings of Internet Explorer (self answered SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41764614/3207406).

[Git repository](https://github.com/oliverpool/go-ieproxy/)

[GoDoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/oliverpool/go-ieproxy) (with an example)

```
package ieproxy

import (
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
)

// StaticProxyConf containes the Windows configuration for static proxy
type StaticProxyConf struct {
    // Is the proxy active?
    Active bool
    // Proxy address for each scheme (http, https)
    // "" (empty string) is the fallback proxy
    Protocols map[string]string
    // Addresses not to be browsed via the proxy (comma-separated, like linux)
    NoProxy string
}

// AutomaticProxyConf contains the Windows configuration for automatic proxy
type AutomaticProxyConf struct {
    URL string // url of the .pac file
}

// WindowsProxyConf gathers the Windows configuration for proxy
type WindowsProxyConf struct {
    Static    StaticProxyConf    // static configuration
    Automatic AutomaticProxyConf // automatic configuration
}


type regeditValues struct {
    ProxyServer   string
    ProxyOverride string
    ProxyEnable   uint64
    AutoConfigURL string
}

var once sync.Once
var windowsProxyConf WindowsProxyConf

// GetConf retrieves the proxy configuration from the Windows Regedit
func getConf() WindowsProxyConf {
    once.Do(parseRegedit)
    return windowsProxyConf
}

// OverrideEnvWithStaticProxy writes new values to the
// http_proxy, https_proxy and no_proxy environment variables.
// The values are taken from the Windows Regedit (should be called in init() function)
func overrideEnvWithStaticProxy() {
    conf := getConf()
    if conf.Static.Active {
        for _, scheme := range []string{"http", "https"} {
            url, ok := conf.Static.Protocols[scheme]
            if !ok {
                url, ok = conf.Static.Protocols[""] // fallback conf
            }
            if ok {
                os.Setenv(scheme+"_proxy", url)
            }
        }
        if conf.Static.NoProxy != "" {
            os.Setenv("no_proxy", conf.Static.NoProxy)
        }
    }
}

func parseRegedit() {
    regedit, _ := readRegedit()

    protocol := make(map[string]string)
    for _, s := range strings.Split(regedit.ProxyServer, ";") {
        if s == "" {
            continue
        }
        pair := strings.SplitN(s, "=", 2)
        if len(pair) > 1 {
            protocol[pair[0]] = pair[1]
        } else {
            protocol[""] = pair[0]
        }
    }

    windowsProxyConf.Static = StaticProxyConf{
        Active:    regedit.ProxyEnable > 0,
        Protocols: protocol,
        NoProxy:   strings.Replace(regedit.ProxyOverride, ";", ",", -1), // to match linux style
    }
    windowsProxyConf.Automatic = AutomaticProxyConf{
        URL: regedit.AutoConfigURL,
    }
}

func readRegedit() (values regeditValues, err error) {
    k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.CURRENT_USER, `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`, registry.QUERY_VALUE)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer k.Close()

    values.ProxyServer, _, err = k.GetStringValue("ProxyServer")
    if err != nil && err != registry.ErrNotExist {
        return
    }
    values.ProxyOverride, _, err = k.GetStringValue("ProxyOverride")
    if err != nil && err != registry.ErrNotExist {
        return
    }

    values.ProxyEnable, _, err = k.GetIntegerValue("ProxyEnable")
    if err != nil && err != registry.ErrNotExist {
        return
    }

    values.AutoConfigURL, _, err = k.GetStringValue("AutoConfigURL")
    if err != nil && err != registry.ErrNotExist {
        return
    }
    err = nil
    return
}
```

I'm interested to know if the "go-style" can be improved and any other suggestions!

Comment: cough-cough .... does this work? `getConf` vs `GetConf` .... hmmm

Comment: @rolfl: actually yes, because [`GetConf` calls `getConf`](https://github.com/oliverpool/go-ieproxy/blob/master/ieproxy.go#L26) (for platform independency), but you are right that it isn't nice to read!

Comment: `GetConf` is/was not defined in the code anywhere... so now it works after your edit, but I see that I had to go to the git repository to find that other file with the `GetConf` declaration.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I also included the struct definitions in my question (which are in the platform independent file as well)

Answer (score 2):

As is, the (my) code is really **hard to test** (needs actual registry modifications or env variable edition).

To ease the testing, one could change some functions:

```
func overrideEnvWithStaticProxy(conf ProxyConf, setenv envSetter) {
    ...
}
type envSetter func(string, string) error

func parseRegedit(regedit regeditValues) ProxyConf {
   ...
}
```

With this change `overrideEnvWithStaticProxy` and `parseRegedit` become self contained and can be easily tested!

This incurs a minor rewrite of `getConf` (which does only some plumbing):

```
func getConf() ProxyConf {
    once.Do(writeConf)
    return windowsProxyConf
}

func writeConf() {
    regedit, _ := readRegedit()
    windowsProxyConf = parseRegedit(regedit)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The field `StaticProxyConf.NoProxy` should not be a single "comma-separated string", but rather a string slice. That makes the code easier that uses this field.

In `readRegedit`, the `err = nil` is not necessary.

Comment: If `StaticProxyConf.NoProxy` becomes a slice, then it has to be joined when the `no_proxy`env variable is set. Without `err = nil`, if the last error is `registry.ErrNotExist`, then this error will be returned (instead of nil). A better approach would be to `return nil` at the end (and remove all unreadable naked returns)